# python 2.7 tix checklist text properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-formatting, tix

I currently have a Checklist that has several levels and sub-levels. I am trying to change the text color and text properties of individual lines in the checklist, however, I am unable to find any information on this. All I can find is how to alter the overall properties of the whole checklist widget. 
Is there a way to append a control character to the .add property similar to this 
`self.cl.hlist.add('cl1.item2',text='Test 2.0',bg='red')` 
 
or is it a different command altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Use `config` to change the text properties

```
self.cl.hlist.config(bg='white',fg = "#191919",bd=0, selectmode='none', selectbackground='White',selectforeground='black', drawbranch=True, pady=2)
```